# this.userId undefined in method called via DDP

Tags: meteor, ddp

This Meteor server failed to fetch the userId inside a method which has been called from a remote DDP.call.  How can I get the userId who called the method from a remote DDP? thx

```js
//app 1 server
let app2_Conn = DDP.connect('http://localhost:4000');
Meteor.methods ({
  'callOut': () => {
    app2_Conn.call('app2_method', args);
  }
});

//app 2 server
Meteor.methods ({
  'app2_method': () => {
    const id = Meteor.userId(); //null
    const iD = this.userId;     //undefined
  }
});
```

Comment: in a method on the server, you should be able to use both Meteor.user() and this.userId. perhaps the (errant) Meteor.userId() call is spoiling your attempt at this.userId?

Comment: Do you mean seeing the id of the user who called `callOut()` in server 2's `this.userId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using an arrow function. Arrow functions change the way the binding of this works.

Change to:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'app2_method'() {
    const id = this.userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it for no avail. `console.log(this.userId)` prints "null" event when I do `'app2_method':function(){}`

Comment: Are you sure a user is logged in?

Comment: In my experience, in Meteor you can use arrow functions for Meteor methods, template helpers, template events or anything where you are defining functions within an object without issue.  Where you run into trouble is using arrow functions in key meteor callbacks (for example template onCreated, onRendered, and onDestroyed).  This will cause `this` binding issues and often flatout break meteor.